# Solve for $y = C\cdot F(x)$ from $y' = y \cos(x)$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

I have this function 
$y^\prime = y \cos(x)$
I want to use integration to reach to the form $y = C\cdot f(x)$.

I can reach to this level $y = e^{\sin(x)+C}$.

How can I solve it? Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{dy}{dx} = y \cos x$$
$$\int \frac{dy}{y} = \int \cos x \ dx$$
$$\log y = \sin x + C$$
$$\implies y = e^{\sin x} \cdot e^C = C’ e^{\sin x}$$

Answer (score 0):

As you and others have shown, your solution is $$y(x) = e^{\cos x + c} = C e^{\cos x}$$

for some $C$.

The only way you can determine $C$ is with initial conditions $(x=0, f(0))$ or other constraints $(x_0, f(x_0))$ or $(x_0, f^\prime (x_0))$...

Answer (score 0):

Mate ,You have got your answer already ,just take 
$$e^c=C$$, from the last line of your answer
$$y=e^{\sin x +c}= e^{\sin x}e^c=Ce^{\sin x}$$
 you are done..